# Hardhat waffle local smart contracts testing: Not enough ether to mint NFT

Tags: ethereum, hardhat, waffle

Error message is:

1. Unit tests
   Governor
   mint first nft:
   Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Not enough ether to purchase NFTs.'
   at MyNftToken.approve (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol:114)
   at MyNftToken.safeMint (contracts/MyNftToken.sol:54)
   at async HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1773:23)
   at async HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:466:16)
   at async EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1504:18)
   at async HardhatNetworkProvider.request (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:118:18)
   at async EthersProviderWrapper.send (node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)

**Prior to running my test I set the ether balance to 10 ether:**

```
await this.token.deployed();
      await hre.network.provider.request({ method: 'hardhat_setBalance', params: [this.signers.admin.address, ethers.utils.parseEther('10').toHexString()] });
```

I mint setting a a gas limit so I don't get the Unable to estimate gas error:

```
const myFirstMint = await this.token.safeMint(this.signers.admin.address, {
      gasLimit: 250000,
    });
    await myFirstMint.wait();
```

Anyone knows what more I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Smart contracts are for security reasons not able to just pull ETH from a wallet - you need to explicitly state how much you want to send while creating the transaction.

ethersjs use the [overrides](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-functionsSend) parameter where you can also specify the amount of wei sent along with the transaction. Example below shows sending 1 ETH (which is 1e18 wei).

```
const myFirstMint = await this.token.safeMint(this.signers.admin.address, {
    gasLimit: 250000,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"),
});
await myFirstMint.wait();
```